# How to include onfocus and onblur events for ASP.NET Menu and MenuItem controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have ASP.NET master page with Menu Control and I need to make it 508 compliance which requires onFocus and onBlur events for keyboard equivalent to OnMouseOver and OnMouseOut event. ASP Menu control doesn't provide these events out of box. I tried Attributes.Add on pageload but it doesn't work for MenuItems.

How can I add onFocus and onBlur events for ASP Menu control?

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server"> 
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Files" Value="File" NavigateUrl="~/HomePage.aspx"> 
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Items" NavigateUrl="/ItemSelect.aspx" /></asp:MenuItem> 
    </Items> 
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
 <Items>
  <asp:MenuItem Text="Files" Value="File" NavigateUrl="~/HomePage.aspx">
 <asp:MenuItem Text="Items" NavigateUrl="/ItemSelect.aspx" />
  </asp:MenuItem>
 </Items>
</asp:Menu>

Comment: I think that's a big job. You will have to see how asp.net renders the menu onto the page in html and drill down to figure out the names/ids/classes of the lists and list items and anchors to figure out how to apply the events to different elements. You might be able to just use the ID of the menu and the anchor tag, if you can apply the events to anchors within the menu.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier than I thought. Getting anchors that are descendents of Menu1, this does the basics:

```
$("#Menu1 a").on("mouseenter", function() {
    alert("mouseover");
});
$("#Menu1 a").on("mouseleave", function() {
    alert("mouseleave");
});
```

Have a look at https://api.jquery.com/on/.

Comment: Wazz, Thanks for your response. I think this works great for stand alone page but my menu is in Master page where the ID gets generated with prefixes, so I am unable to tag the <A> tags which get generated from ASP Menu control.

Comment: I web.config, inside `<system.web>`, add `<pages clientIDMode="Static">`. This will ensure IDs are not changed by ASP.NET.